# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: when trying to debug in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I was trying to Debug my application by running it from Eclipse after passing the arguments in the Debug configuration > Arguments . But im getting the error as below

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: C:\bea\jrockit_160_05\jre\bin\java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\bea\jrockit_160_05\jre\bin\java
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
Exception in thread "main" 

"C:\bea\jrockit_160_05\jre\bin\java" -Xms256m -Xmx256m -XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=1000M ---------etc
```

etc are the arguments im passed .

Please help me to resolve this